# Spring Boot can't read application.properties in Docker

Tags: spring, docker, intellij-idea, spring-boot, dockerfile

Spring Boot doesn't read application properties when running in Docker container.

My **application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080
  context-path: /mail
custom:
  greeting: Hello YML
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8-jre
VOLUME /tmp
COPY ./mail.jar /app/mail.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app/mail.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app/mail.jar" ]
EXPOSE 8080
```

And a simple **ApplicationController**

```
@RestController
public class ApplicationController {

  private final Environment environment;

  @Autowired
  public ApplicationController(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  @RequestMapping(path = "/")
  public Hello hello() {
    final Hello hello = new Hello();
    hello.setGreeting(environment.getProperty("custom.greeting"));
    return hello;
  }
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ Docker plugin that automatically map ports 8080(docker):18080(host) and makes app available on **http://localhost:18080**

**Docker**

1. server.context-path property isn't applied. App still available with **/** and not with **/mail/**
2. custom.greeting property not reads from properties file and controller returns **{"greeting":null}** instead **{"greeting":"Hello YML"}**

**Without Docker**

3. context-path applied properly
4. custom.greeting property returns by controller properly

Comment: where is your `application.yml` file ? it seems it's not on the classpath, i.e. not included in the fat jar that you ship in your docker image.

Comment: Application.yml under src/main/resources path and it's on the class path. I also added @PropertySource annotation and got the same issue

Comment: Add `spring-boot-starter-actuator` and see what the endpoint `/env` tells you about your environment. You should see something like `"applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]" : { "custom.greeting" : "..." }`

Comment: When run without docker I can get all info that `/env` tells. And I get an error when run in Docker container: _There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)._

Comment: is the application.yml under the `\src\main\resources`? why don't you use this instead? `@Value("${custom.greeting}")`
    `private String greeting;`

Comment: @PavelOvchinnikov did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @Paizo that shouldn't be an issue right? the way you access your env variables shouldn't matter

Comment: @ricardoespsanto Clean re-creating project solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the application.properties file in the docker /app/ directory. Ur docker directory structure will be

```
app
   -main.jar
   -application.properties
```

You can do so by using `ADD /ur/local/location/application.properties /app/application.properties`

Then better write this command in your docker file

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java" ,"-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom --spring.config.location=classpath:file:/app/application-properties","-jar","/app/main.jar"]
```

Your whole dockerFile should look like this:

```
FROM java:8-jre
VOLUME /tmp
COPY ./mail.jar /app/mail.jar
ADD /ur/local/location/application.properties /app/application.properties
ENTRYPOINT ["java" ,"-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom --spring.config.location=classpath:file:/app/application-properties","-jar","/app/main.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename Application.yml to application.yml. It's with reference to the name used in the comments as Application.yml.

Application.yml works well with widows but breaks inside linux containers.

Answer (score 0):

For the context path, you have to add the context path in the properties file.
inside the  **application-default.properties**:

> server.servlet.contextPath=/myContext

Then build your project,

> mvn clean install

Then create a docker image and run that image.