# How to add yaml config for Spirnboot in docker?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, yaml, config

I have a Springboot application called log-preprocessor with YAML config, that runs ok locally. I would like to dockerize it. 
My `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:8u181-jre-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /log-preprocessor
WORKDIR /log-preprocessor

COPY ./target/dependency-jars /log-preprocessor/dependency-jars/
COPY ./target/application.jar /log-preprocessor/

CMD java -jar application.jar
```

It builds and starts application correctly, but then it says it is missing variables from the YAML config file. How can I add that config file to the docker? The config file is located on standard path for Springboot: `/conf/application.yml`

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235946/spring-boot-cant-read-application-properties-in-docker ? It should be similar

Comment: I checked it now, and it helped. Thanks.